# how to use spring's @IntegrationTest in main method?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-test

i have a spring boot application. sometimes i need to launch long running report generation. the easiest way was to create an `@IntegrationTest` to use spring's `@Autowire`:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=Application.class)
@IntegrationTest
public class ReportGenerationTest {

    @Autowired MyService myService;
    @Value("classpath:/test.txt") Resource testData; //it's in test, not in src

    @Test 
    public void generate_report() {

       report(myService, testData);
    }
}
```

it works perfectly. but i don't want it to be run with every build. i also don't want to add/remove `@Ignore` as sooner or later someone will accidentally commit it without `@Ignore` and i don't want to do any code editing just to run reports

ideally i would like it to be a `main` method run on demand. but how can i manually create a spring context for the src service and test resources?

i need something like:

```java
public class MyReport {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReportGenerationTest reportGenerator = getAutowiredInstanceFromSpring();    
    reportGenerator.generate_report();
  }
}
```

Comment: Only run the test for a given profile, deactivate by default.

Comment: but it requires every single developer to configure his IDE to run this specific test with a profile. i would rather spend more time building a solution to make it simple to everyone calling it later

Comment: So and how is that different that hack (because it really is) a solution then run a test with a `-Dspring.profiles.active`.? It is a single run configuration. Either they need to know how to run it, if it is a test run it as a test, don't try to hide it as as main method and do ugly things to make it work